# How do you use rbind to combine and export 4 csv files?

Tags: r, csv, rbind, write.table

Just a heads up that I am very new to coding; sorry if this seems very rudimentary! I have tried looking this up and watching tutorials and still am not figuring out what's wrong. I have 4 csv files that all have the same column names. I am trying to merge them all into one combined spreadsheet by stacking them all together (because the column names all match) using rbind() in RStudio.

However, it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code I have:

```
merged = rbind(inspections.0,inspections.1,inspections.2,inspections.3,inspections.4)

write.table(merged,file = 'inspections_all.csv',sep = ',', row.names=F, col.names=T)
```

When I run the code, it displays "> write.table(merged,file = 'osha_inspections_all.csv',sep = ',', row.names=F, col.names=T)
**Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'merged' not found**"

I have spent over an hour trying to figure this out and am just very lost on what the problem is. Is the issue with rbind()? Or is the issue with the way I am using write.table()?

I would appreciate any help if possible! Thanks so much!

Comment: Run the `rbind(...)` line on its own and see if there is an error at that point. The error you are getting suggests that `merged` was never created, and that something went wrong with the `rbind`

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! No error when I do that - when I run it the console does just display the same line of code for the rbind() line; I'm not sure if that means it's working or if nothing actually happened...

Comment: Type `merged` + hit enter,  now into the console and check that it displays your data. As far as I can tell, your `rbind` line is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
merged <- do.call("rbind", list(inspections.0,inspections.1,inspections.2,inspections.3,inspections.4))
```

Check dimensions:

```
dim(merged)
```

And export:

```
write.table(merged, file = 'inspections_all.csv', sep = ',', row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
```